# Conversion from avi to wmv

Tags: c#, bitmap, avi, wmv

I would like to make an avi to wmv convertor on my own. For this, my understanding is I'd study the internal structure of an avi file and extract frame by frame and put in the way wmv encodes the frames. I would like to draw suggestions for learning the pattern of wmv. Is there any online documentation for a layman.

Comment: avi and wmv don't have normal frames. wmv has difference frames and avi can be in any number of formats. you need to know codecs, and probably know thing like CUDA so the conversion won't take years.

Comment: AVI is a container format. You still need to apply codecs to extract frames. This is most definitely not a subject for the layman.

Comment: i'm looking into wmv9, but has not found a simple documentation.

Comment: It's not simple. Simple documentation cannot exist. This task is almost certainly far too hard for you. Start with something easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi Windows SDK is your best friend:

- [Learn Windows: Audio and Video Development](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/bb190307.aspx)
- [Microsoft Windows
  Software Development Kit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/bb980924.aspx)

**Edit**:

find more info about WMV here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Media_Video

Comment: ? and how do you think you can manipulate those files? with filestream I/O byte by byte?

Comment: Is this homework? if you use byte/binary reads to get the header information and parse metadata and frames from the stream you are going torwards such headache...  if you use apis at least you abstract from this and Apis will probably work also with newer formats while ad hoc code may or may not. There was a very famous website I used some years ago with all file extensions specifications and links to docs for all of them but not remember the name now...

Comment: i'm trying to dive into deep is for understanding those things...is it digitalpreservation website you're referring to?

Answer (score 1):

Here you can find the WMV/ASF specifications:

[Advanced Systems Format (ASF) Specification](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=14995)

Comment: in simple words.., what I would like to know is to interpret what is shown when a wmv file is opened in a text editor. I want to decode it.